# Prevent intent.action on my site

Tags: android, html, web, action

I have a question about android intent.action.
 On my site I have a link `<a href...>` to several social network. And if I make tap on this link - andoid give me a popup with chose an application to open this link. 
Can I prevent this action?
 Maybe I can use data-* attributes on my link, or any other (maybe meta-tag, like `<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">` )?

P.S. I made wifi hot-spot with autorization throught social network. And if client try click "authorize with facebook" then will be show popup with application chose.

Comment: Are you talking about your web application or you have a application which shows content into webview?

Comment: @PankajKumar I talking about web application.